# Karma-Runner on Ubuntu: 'usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory' error

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I am trying to set up the JavaScript code tester Karma, but when I run the command to initialise karma I get the error 'usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory'. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per @digitalmediums

> I've found this is often a misnaming error, if you install from a package manager you bin may be called nodejs so you just need to symlink it like so "sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node"

Answer (score 2):

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
 this worked for me. 
 node is a reserved term in ubuntu thus node.js  is actually nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question with same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886217/browserify-error-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory/32371807#32371807)

Usually the non packaged node version (not nodejs) that the user installs can be run from /usr/local/bin/node

as

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node
```