# Sudo user not using same node version

Tags: linux, node.js

I have a strange issue on my server, when ever i try to install packages with `npm` that require `sudo` I run into issues and i have discovered that my `su` and regular user use different node versions.

```
$ node -v i get node version  0.10.x
```

But when i do:

```
$ sudo node -v i get node version 0.6.x
```

My `su` user for some reason is using a different node version than what i normally use and this causes compatibility issues when I `npm install` packages that require `sudo`.

I have tried sudo apt-get upgrade nodejs at no luck. how do i make su user use same node version as my regular user.

Comment: What is the output of `which node` for both?

Comment: And which distribution & version do you use?

Comment: have you installed `node` via `nvm`??

Comment: Probably you should uninstall node for your regular user and then sudo npm install -g nodejs so there is only one global copy of node that everyone uses.

Comment: regular user : 
/root/.nvm/v0.10.13/bin/node
sudo: 
/usr/bin/node

Comment: Ive also updated node for sudo, but i dont want different nodes per user.

Comment: it seems that the regular user is using node thru NVM and the sudo is using the regular installed node.

Comment: Just a quick update. i ran $ nvm deactivate which removed the nvm shell directive. now when i run node -v the versions match. when i run which node i get both identical versions and path. THANKS ALL!

Comment: Alon Carmel,  correct when I ran nvm deactivate , problem solved.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

run `ll /usr/bin/node` if this file exist, simply run `rm /usr/local/bin/node` from the regular user

**explanation**

If you'd run which `node` from regular user you will probably see it points to the user local bin directory

```
which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

this means that the regular user installed another node version locally.

to let the same node version apply to all users, this command should show you usr bin (not local).

```
which node 
/usr/bin/node
```

by deleting the link from `/usr/local/bin/node` it will automatically start using `/usr/bin/node`

Comment: when i run the ll /usr/bin/node i get: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Oct  2 07:11 /usr/bin/node -> /etc/alternatives/node*

Comment: Just a quick update. i ran $ nvm deactivate which removed the nvm shell directive. now when i run node -v the versions match. when i run which node i get both identical versions and path.  i marked this as answer because this made me look for the other node and delete the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Try running sudo with the environment of the user:

```
sudo -E node -v
```

Comment: but after it shows the wrong version, how do you fix it and switch the version?

Comment: this does not work (for me at least)... the same versioning difference can be observed

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem right after upgrading to a newer version of node (6 -> 7)

The above solution did not work for me as I do not the file `/usr/local/bin/node` but I was in fact getting different verions from running `npm --version` and `sudo npm --version`

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036278/npm-is-incorrect-version-on-latest-ubuntu-18-04-installation

The answer states that bash was caching the older version of node.

simply running `hash -d npm`

Comment: are you talking about `npm`? This thread is about `node`...

Comment: OP states he was originally trying to install packages with `npm`.  My response has its implcit relevance

Answer (score -1):

```bash
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Comment: You might notice that upvoted answers tend to be those who describe the immediate effect of a given code solution and explain why that helps to solve a given problem. In contrast to thast, your post is unexplained code only.