# No such file or directory when trying to run after npm install -g

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, vagrant

I am using Vagrant to run the default linux VM (with admin privilleges so that symlink works)

After installing a package with `npm install -g <package>`, I am unable to run the symlink created (as a shortcut to run from path).

The file contents as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var arguments = process.argv.slice(2);
var fs = require('fs');
var usage = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/usage.txt').toString();

if (arguments.length < 3) {
    console.error(usage);
    return;
}

var summon = require('./Summoner');

summon(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);
```

Running the file with `<filename>` directly doesn't work, throwing `: No such file or directory`, whereas running it with `node <filename>` will work.

I have tried `npm install -g gulp` and running `gulp` works perfectly. Checking the contents of `gulp`, I see that the `#!/usr/bin/env node` line is exactly the same as this file, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

check if the node executable is in /usr/bin/env

Comment: maybe you can look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886217/browserify-error-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: the link you posted has the problem of `node` not being linked to `nodejs`, but my `node` seems to be linked properly

Answer (score 0):

Check the symlink that has been created for the module that you installed and whether it is executable by your user.

`ls -l $(which summon)`

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Nov 17 18:20 /usr/bin/eportal -> ../lib/node_modules/eportal/cli.js` is what I got back

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem due to the fact that my Node project's `bin/script` had `CR+LF` line endings instead of Linux `LF`-only line endings.