# What's the equivalent of Ubuntu's apt-get command on a Mac?

Tags: linux, macos

Can someone tell me how to install a software using the terminal on mac please?
i tried the apt-get but it's specific to Linux so it doesn't work on mac!!

Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is apt-get function not working in terminal on mac osx 10.9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688424/why-is-apt-get-function-not-working-in-terminal-on-mac-osx-10-9)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) which fills the third-party package manager niche for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MacPorts using the following commands for instance:

```
port install <name of package>
port selfupdate
```

Look here https://www.macports.org/

Answer (score 0):

Mac doesn't have the same built in package managers as other OSes.

You'll have to choose a package manager you want and get it via curl or manually downloading it. Check out [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) which is as simple as:

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`