# couldn't install psycopg2 for a FastAPI project on macOs 10.13.6 : python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully

Tags: python, psycopg2

I tried to install **psycopg2** with the command line :

`pip install psycopg2`
and this is what I get

```
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:463: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      running egg_info
      creating /private/var/folders/lx/rssnrrbj15jcz8pj88rr89f00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-lpapm88u/psycopg2.egg-info
      writing /private/var/folders/lx/rssnrrbj15jcz8pj88rr89f00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-lpapm88u/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/lx/rssnrrbj15jcz8pj88rr89f00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-lpapm88u/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/lx/rssnrrbj15jcz8pj88rr89f00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-lpapm88u/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/lx/rssnrrbj15jcz8pj88rr89f00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-lpapm88u/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      
      Error: pg_config executable not found.
      
      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:
      
          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
      
      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
      
      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

then I tried to download the package from the official web site and put in the PATH:

`/Users/t/PycharmProjects/API/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages`
(Im using a virtual environement) but I get  **No module named 'psycopg2'**

Comment: Use `pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: @Irfanuddin I tried, but I get  No module named 'psycopg2 when I import it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading some similar questions on Stackoverflow here is the solution that worked for me.

First, install **Homebrew** in case you don't already have it installed

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

then install postgresql :

`brew install postgresql`

finally use the pip command to install psycpg2 :

`pip install psycopg2`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

it is helped me

Comment: I get command not found

Comment: @HamzaDevXX It is because this command is for Linux and you are on macOS. There is no `apt` on macOS.

Comment: `sudo get install libpq-dev`still not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369363/whats-the-equivalent-of-ubuntus-apt-get-command-on-a-mac